# Is it possible to count or tally in a registry key how many times this button is pushed?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, registry

I don't know the basic of it I'm newbie. How to do it in c#.

Is it possible to count or tally in a registry key how many times this button is pushed?

Comment: *"I don't know the basic of it I'm newbie"*. Then learn. We're not here to teach you the basics. We're here to help you with specific issues but, if you haven't tried, you haven't encountered an issue yet.

Comment: Also, if you want help with C#, don't tag your question VB.NET. Tags are supposed to indicate the content of your question, not the people you want to look at it.

Comment: jmcilhinney, please always try for help not for taunt.

Comment: There was no taunt there. There was instruction. This site is supposed to be used in a specific way and you didn't do that. If you don't want to be criticised then don't do the wrong thing. The definition of "help" is not just giving you whatever information you want regardless of whether you post an appropriate question or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can be divided into two parts :

1. Getting the number of times the button is pressed.

Assuming this is a keyboard key you are referring to, you can look into `KeyPress` event on `Control` that can get you started. [Documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress?view=netcore-3.1)

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   // Check for e.KeyChar property to match with your needed key.
   // ButtonClick++; //A counter to keep  a track of button clicks
}
```

2. Entering the ButtonClick value in registry

This can be achieved using the `Registry.SetValue()` [Documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry.setvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

You can get/set the key like this and use it accordingly in your code.

```
using (RegistryKey myKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\YourCompanyName\SomeNewKey"))
{
    int count = 0;
    if (myKey != null)
    {
        count = Convert.ToInt32(myKey.GetValue("myKey"));
    }
    myKey.SetValue("myKey", ++count, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
}
```